# How to send targeted notifications to a widget with Flutter Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, notifications, riverpod

My Flutter app has a large number of tiny Stateful Widgets. I want to send a notification to one of them, and induce it to change state. What is the exact mechanism with Riverpod (or any other notification system like Value Change Notifier or Streams) to send a message to a particular widget? I can assign a custom id for each widget, or use a globally unique key to identify them.

If you need some context: My app has a monitoring panel with 100 lamps, resembling physical LEDs, arranged in a 10x10 matrix on the screen. These are custom widgets based on Avatars. Each lamp represents a status (on/off) or an error condition. When a sensor in the physical world raises an alarm, the corresponding widget gets a notification, and the lamp glows red on the UI.

I don't think I should create 100 Riverpod Notifier-Provider objects. But if have a single Notifier, it will  invoke the `build()` method of all the 100 widgets, which is not the goal.  I want to tell Riverpod something like this: "Your state has changed. The new value is `{'lamp_id' : 42, 'status' : 'on' }`. But send this notification only to lamp number 42, and not to the other 99 widgets."

I have no server side infrastructure like Firebase push notifications. Please suggest any client-only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a [family class-based provider](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/about_code_generation#passing-parameters-to-a-provider-family) for this. Add an `id` parameter to the class-based provider's `build` method.

```dart
@riverpod
class LampStatus extends _$LampStatus {
  @override
  bool build(int id) => false;

  void turnOn() {
    state = true;
  }
}
```

In your lamp widget, watch the provider like this:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final status = ref.watch(lampStatusProvider(id));
  
  // ...
}
```

This way, each lamp widget will have its own provider, even though you only defined the provider once.

When you call `ref.read(lampStatusProvider(id).notifier).turnOn()` somewhere, it will correctly change the status only for the lamp with the given `id`.

Comment: Excellent tip-off! 
Interestingly, I had seen the link you have provided. But since the documentation is so poor, I could not make out the connection between the provider and the Consumer, and could not decipher the purpose of Family Provider. After receiving your hint, I could successfully implement it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the very useful hint of `@Dhafin Rayhan` and solved the problem of client-specific notifications using Riverpod.

Documentation on this is virtually non-existent or not easy to find. So I am placing the missing pieces for anyone's reference.

First you create a `FamilyNotifier` with any template. Pass a parameter to the `build()` function that will identify a particular listener target.

```
//Family Notifier and provider in Riverpod:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final myUserProvider = NotifierProviderFamily<UserNotifier, String, int>(UserNotifier.new);

class UserNotifier extends FamilyNotifier<String, int> {
  UserNotifier();

  @override
  String build(int userid) {
    return 'Guest'; // initial value
  }

  void setUser(String newValue) {
    state = newValue;
  }
}
```

Then create a top level `NotifierProviderFamily` object that clients can subscribe to. Only the listener registering with the correct id will receive the notification.

```
//Event sender - ConsumerStatefulWidget:
ref.read(myUserProvider(123).notifier).setUser('Jack');
ref.read(myUserProvider(456).notifier).setUser('Jill');

//Event receiver - ConsumerWidget1:
String name = ref.watch(myUserProvider(123)); // will receive 'Jack'

// Event receiver - ConsumerWidget2:
String name = ref.watch(myUserProvider(456)); // will receive 'Jill'
```

Comment: One catch, though. Using parameterized Families greatly simplifies my code. But I am not sure whether 100  separate instances of the Provider object  will still be created.  Will this be scalable? Somebody may please throw light on this.
If there is something like MQTT protocol, (that is based on broadcasting) for inter-widget communication in Flutter, please let me know.